# How to fix 'Status and headers already sent' when refreshing react-app/webflux?

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-websocket, okta

I was following steps given in [webflux-websocket-okta-blog](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/09/25/spring-webflux-websockets-react), with `R2DBC` and `spring-data`.

After I had finished all the steps and tested the expected outcome in between, I expected to have the `react` webpage where the inserted records via a create script into the DB would be directly presented on screen.

This would be made possible via the `reactive websocket` that sends messages out when an insert is done. This should lead to the message arriving at the listener side in the react-app. The messages contain a header with an access-token.

But instead of messages arriving I get the:

> 'IllegalStateException: Status and headers already sent'

in the console when I open `localhost:3000` (react-app page). The app still functions and I can refresh, but this just triggers the getAll and not via the expected (without F5) direct websocket/message way.

I read that this problem has come across earlier after the Spring-boot upgrade to 2.1.5, but had been resolved in later versions. I downgraded to 2.2.1 but still had the same problem.
 My project is: [github-reactive-spring-tour](https://github.com/Vlisie/reactivetourapp)

I get following in my stacktrace:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Status and headers already sent  at
>   reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.addHeader(HttpServerOperations.java:192)
>   ~[reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorServerHttpResponse.applyCookies(ReactorServerHttpResponse.java:97)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.http.server.reactive.AbstractServerHttpResponse.lambda$doCommit$11(AbstractServerHttpResponse.java:238)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoRunnable.subscribe(MonoRunnable.java:49)
>   ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4105)
>   ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatArray.java:207)
>   ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray.subscribe(FluxConcatArray.java:80)
>   ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoFromFluxOperator.subscribe(MonoFromFluxOperator.java:72)
>   ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
>   ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:153)
>   ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.ignoreDone(MonoIgnoreThen.java:190)
>   ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreInner.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240)
>   ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]   at
>   reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:1871)
>   ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]

```js
async componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    isLoading: true
  });
  const headers = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + await this.props.auth.getAccessToken()
    }
  };

  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8088/renners', headers);
  const data = await response.json();
  this.setState({
    renners: data,
    isLoading: false
  });

  const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8088/ws/renners');
  socket.addEventListener('message', async(event: any) => {
    const renner = JSON.parse(event.data);
    this.state.renners.push(renner);
    this.setState({
      renners: this.state.renners
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. I've just bumpbed spring-boot version to 2.4.0 and it  started working.